# Why can't I get a huge font? (text along curved path)

Tags: text-decorations

Here's my current document:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
 \usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
 \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
       \begin{tikzpicture}
          \path [decorate, decoration={text along path, text={ |\fontsize{60pt}{4em}\selectfont| Annual Picnic ||}}] (0,0) .. controls (8,2) .. (16,0);
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

**QUESTIONS**

(1)  How can I get this to work with a large font that will essentially cover the entire top of the page?

(2)  What are some other ways of arranging text along part of a circle at the top of the page?

Comment: Try to change the font size before the picture.

Comment: Because LaTeXs NFSS have some curious problem. You can declare `\font\f=cmr17 at60pt` and you can say `\text={ |\f| Annual Picnic ||}` and the problem vanishes.

Comment: @wipet not really fitting with the rest of latex

Comment: @Sigur you can change the font anywhere but latex will change it back, and tell you in the log file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This shows that the problem is LaTeX itself. You need some another package to fix this bug, package which is used by non-standard way: before `\documentclass`. The usage `\font\f` is more natural and without problems and without packages to fix these problems :)

Comment: It's not a problem it's by design. fix-cm is part of the base distribution so it's only a "problem" in the same way that it's a "problem" that you need a class such as `article` before you can use `\section`. `\f` works of course in this simple case as there are no font changes and no line breaking within its scope, but it doesn't really work and isn't good advice in a latex context (as you know)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle IMHO it *is* problem of design. The old times are shown here: when only limited number of bitmap fonts were prepared and ready. And NFSS are from this time. Nowadays, user can be surprised why fonts cannot be scaled to arbitrary size *by default*, without any additional package or fix-package.

Comment: @wipet perhaps you don't care about document stability and that a document from earlier times shouldn't start using different fonts and different line breaks. That's fine, but the design of latex and plain tex are deeply routed around that principle. It isn't a general feature, if you choose a scalable font such as times or latin modern or .. then all sizes are available, but if you take the default cm set you get the original sizes unless you specify you wantto change that. You may not like it but that is not a bug, and if you want different sizes using a primitive `\font` isn't the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell latex you have cm as scalable fonts

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
 \usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
 \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
       \begin{tikzpicture}
          \path [decorate, decoration={text along path, text={ |\fontsize{60pt}{4em}\selectfont| Annual Picnic ||}}] (0,0) .. controls (8,2) .. (16,0);
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
 \end{document}
```